# C++ multiple inheritance ambiguous

Tags: c++

I have a problem in C++ multiple inheritance. here is my code and when I call display() function it is giving me request for member `display' is ambiguous. But Class M display() function is private.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;
class M
{

    void display()
    {
        cout<<"Class M"<<endl;
    }
};

class N
{
    public:
        void display()
        {
            cout<<"Class N"<<endl;
        }
};

class P:public M,public N
{

};

int main()
{

    P *ob = new P();
    ob->display();    // Why its giving me ambiguity error? Since only one copy is there right!!
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Can any one tell why exactly this problem?

Comment: The ambiguity error is because despite the scope of the function in `M`, the call is ambiguous.  Try using the scope resolution operator `::` to help resolve where the call should be made: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b451xz31.aspx

Comment: visibility doesn't restrict the choice in overload.

Comment: You can resolve it by putting `using N::display` in the public interface of `P`.

Comment: thanks Martin and Joren. I got it..

Answer (score 4):

As was mentioned by many already, overload resolution does not include visibility (`public`, `private` and `protected`). Assuming you want only the public version visible in `P`, you should use a `using` declaration in the public interface of `P`:

```
class P: public M, public N
{
public:
    using N::display;
};
```

IMHO, this is far more elegant than having to provide the scope in every call (`obj->N::display()`).

Comment: Thanks Joren.   This helps

Answer (score 1):

Basically in C++, in case of multiple inheritance the derived class gets a copy of all methods of all parents. So when you do `new P()`, the new objects gets two different methods, with same name `display()`. And therefore there is an ambiguity.
Scope resolution will help you here.

```
//define function pointer
void (N::*pfn)() = &N::display;
//call function using pointer
(ob->*pfn)();
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution of ambiguity in multiple inheritance: The ambiguity can be resolved by using the scope resolution operator to specify the class in which the member function lies as given below:

```
obj.a :: abc();
```

This statement invoke the function name abc() which are lies in base class a.